# How to give distanceToEdge in react-native-floating-action for every pages

Tags: react-native

I have added a floating icon from react-native-floating-action package. I need to apply the different position for different pages, how to apply, this is my code. Its not working.

```
floatingIconEdge = () => {
    // floating icon showing edges for different screens
    const { currentScreen } = this.state
    switch (currentScreen) {
        case 'ShopScreen':
            return { vertical: 40, horizontal: 10 }
        case 'StoreHome':
            return { vertical: 10, horizontal: 10 }
        default:
            return { vertical: 40, horizontal: 40 }
    }

}<FloatingAction
    actions={actions}
    floatingIcon={<Icon name={'ios-help-circle-outline'} style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#ffffff' }} />}
    onPressItem={name => {
        Reactotron.error({ name });
        NavigationService.navigate('ChatRoom')
    }}
    distanceToEdge={this.floatingIconEdge()}
    color={'#2cb673'}
    visible={this.floatingIconVisible()}
/>
```

Comment: Are you setting  this.sate.currentScreen  correctly in every page?

Comment: Yes, this.state.current screen working correctly. I think floatingIconEdge function has error. but I could not resolve

Comment: I dont see ```const``` in floatingIconEdge() declaration.

Comment: distanceToEdge={this.state.currentScreen == 'ShopScreen' ? { vertical: 10, horizontal: 10 } : { vertical: 40, horizontal: 40 }}

Comment: Is this correct, but it takes only Horizontal:10, not takes the vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    OneSignal.init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState((status) => {
        console.log(status);
        Reactotron.error({ oneSignalErrStatus: status });
    });
    AsyncStorage.setItem('CameraChoice', '0');
    this.state = {
        currentScreen: '',
        distanceToEdge: { vertical: 40, horizontal: 10 }
    };
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}
componentDidMount() {
    // TODO set this.state.currentScreen
    Reactotron.log('didMount>>>>>');
    this.floatingIconEdge()
}
onReceived = (notification) => {
    console.log('Notification received: ', notification);
    Reactotron.error({ log: 'notification', place: 'inside onReceived', notification });
};

onOpened = (openResult) => {
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
    Reactotron.error({ log: 'notification', place: 'inside onOpenend', notification: openResult.notification });
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
};

onIds = (device) => {
    Reactotron.error({ log: 'notification', place: 'inside onIds', notification: device });
    console.log('Device info: ', device);
};

// gets the current screen from navigation state
getActiveRouteName = (navigationState) => {
    if (!navigationState) {
        return null;
    }
    const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
    // dive into nested navigators
    if (route.routes) {
        return this.getActiveRouteName(route);
    }
    return route.routeName;
};

floatingIconVisible = () => {
    // floating icon showing or not if user is logged in or not.
    const { currentScreen } = this.state
    if (checkLoggedIn()) {
        if (currentScreen == 'ChatRoom') {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }

    // switch (currentScreen) {
    //  case 'PhoneSignup':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'WelcomeReorder':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'CreateAccount':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'NumberVerification':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'ChatRoom':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'ReceiptScreen':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'MainCamera':
    //      return false;
    //  case 'VendingCamera':
    //      return false;
    //  default:
    //      return true;
}

floatingIconEdge = () => {
    // floating icon showing edges for different screens
    const { currentScreen } = this.state
    Reactotron.log({ currentScreen1111: currentScreen });
    switch (currentScreen) {
        case 'ShopScreen':
            this.setState({ distanceToEdge: { vertical: 0, horizontal: 0 } })
        case 'StoreHome':
            this.setState({ distanceToEdge: { vertical: 0, horizontal: 0 } })
        default:
            this.setState({ distanceToEdge: { vertical: 40, horizontal: 40 } })
    }
    // if (currentScreen == 'ShopScreen') {
    //  Reactotron.log({ if: 'if' });
    //  return { vertical: 500, horizontal: 40 }
    // }
    // else {
    //  Reactotron.log({ else: 'else' });
    //  // return { horizontal: 10, vertical: 10 }
    // }

}

/**
 * Render method
 *
 * @return {component}
 */
render() {
    const { store, persistor } = getStore();
    const actions = [
        {
            text: 'Start Chat',
            icon: <Icon name={'ios-chatboxes'} style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#ffffff' }} />,
            name: 'chat',
            position: 2,
            color: '#2cb673'
        },
        {
            text: 'Ping Retailer',
            icon: <Icon name={'ios-hand'} style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#ffffff' }} />,
            name: 'ping',
            position: 1,
            color: '#2cb673'
        }
        // {
        //     text: "Location",
        //     icon: require("./images/ic_room_white.png"),
        //     name: "bt_room",
        //     position: 3
        // },
        // {
        //     text: "Video",
        //     icon: require("./images/ic_videocam_white.png"),
        //     name: "bt_videocam",
        //     position: 4
        // }
    ];

    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={appSyncClient}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    {/* <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}> */}
                    {/* <Router
                        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
                            const currentScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(currentState);
                            this.setState({currentScreen});
                            // const prevScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(prevState);

                            // if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
                            //     // the line below uses the Google Analytics tracker
                            //     // change the tracker here to use other Mobile analytics SDK.
                            //     Reactotron.error({log:'NAVIGATION STATE CHANGE', prevScreen, currentScreen});
                            // }
                        }} 
                        ref={navigatorRef => {
                            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
                        }}    
                    /> */}
                    <AppContainer
                        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState, action) => {
                            const currentScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(currentState);
                            this.setState({ currentScreen });
                            firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen(currentScreen);
                            store.dispatch(setCurrentScreen({ name: currentScreen }));
                            if (
                                action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' ||
                                action.type === 'Navigation/DRAWER_CLOSED' ||
                                action.type === 'Navigation/RESET' ||
                                (action.type === 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING' && !action.willShow)
                            ) {
                                if (store.getState().currentScreen.isDrawerOpen) {
                                    StatusBar.setHidden(false);
                                    store.dispatch(setDrawerStatus(false));
                                }
                            } else if (
                                action.type === 'Navigation/DRAWER_OPENED' ||
                                action.type === 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_ACTIVE' ||
                                (action.type === 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING' && action.willShow)
                            ) {
                                if (!store.getState().currentScreen.isDrawerOpen) {
                                    // StatusBar.setHidden(true);
                                    store.dispatch(setDrawerStatus(true));
                                }
                            }
                            // const prevScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(prevState);

                            // if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
                            //     // the line below uses the Google Analytics tracker
                            //     // change the tracker here to use other Mobile analytics SDK.
                            //     Reactotron.error({log:'NAVIGATION STATE CHANGE', prevScreen, currentScreen});
                            // }
                        }}
                        ref={(navigatorRef) => {
                            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
                        }}
                    />
                    {/* </PersistGate> */}
                    <LoginModal navigation={NavigationService} />
                    <CategoryTransaction />
                    { /* Floating Icon  */}
                    <FloatingAction
                        actions={actions}
                        floatingIcon={<Icon name={'ios-help-circle-outline'} style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#ffffff' }} />}
                        onPressItem={name => {
                            Reactotron.error({ name });
                            NavigationService.navigate('ChatRoom')
                        }}
                        distanceToEdge={this.state.distanceToEdge}
                        // distanceToEdge={{ vertical: 40, horizontal: 40 }}
                        color={'#2cb673'}
                        visible={this.floatingIconVisible()}
                    // style={{ margin: 2000 }}
                    />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

}

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Router);
export default App;

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class for the floating button and then you can modify it for each screen like you want using props.
Here is an exemple: https://snack.expo.io/BJLGJl36r

Comment: Hey its takes state value as default

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, mark it as solution please. You can give also +1 if you want. Thanks